# Forwarding emails to nonexisting users/aliases to external mail server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, migration

I'm in the works of installing a postfix mailserver on a machine **currently being used as web server**. As of right now, I've got it working as far as that I can send and receive emails using telnet through port 25.

However, as my customer is concerned with downtime, I'd like to setup all the accounts one by one over time, and making sure it works, rather than just cutting the cord to the old mail server and start creating new accounts on the new system.

**How can I add the domain *customer.com* to my mail server and just add something like *test@customer.com* to the users and aliases-lists without the web server trying to send all emails with the *@customer.com* domain to the new mail server?**

I'm running ubuntu, using postfix and postfix-mysql on the new machine, the old mail server is on a hosted environment somewhere else, where I don't have any control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using transport maps to send mail to the new server for migrated accounts and to the old server for accounts that have not been migrated yet.

http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Comment: Do you have any experience with this kind of setup? Can I do something like `line 1: test@customer.com -> in my environment; line 2: @customer.com -> send to relay;` like a catch all for the adresses not in the list, if you get what I mean?

Comment: As documented in transport(5), domain wildcards are supported.